# Pandas not found in Visual Studio Code even though it is definitely in the env

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, importerror

I am running Visual Studio Code on two machines, both set up essentially the same way. One is an iMac, the other a MacBook Air. In one of my projects, on the iMac, it doesn't recognize that pandas is installed, even though it is in the environment.

Here is the VSC python interpreter selection:

[image]

And here you can see that:

1. it is not able to import pandas
2. I'm in the env
3. pip3 freeze shows pandas
4. pip3 install indicates that pandas is already present

[image]

I've tried uninstalling pandas and reinstalling it, but that doesn't help. I've tried making sure it's in the non-env python install (it is), but that doesn't help.

I have other projects on the same computer set up essentially the same way, and pandas works fine. I also have the same project on my laptop, with the same setup, and it is working there too. I'm kinda stumped. I guess I'll be working on it on the laptop for now, but I'd appreciate any insight people may have...

### Edits

- if I run the code directly in the terminal, using the venv, it works fine
- pip3 shows pandas 1.1.1 in the terminal; still haven't figured out whether I can get VSC to show me what it's seeing.
- I figured out how to call pip from inside Python, and when I call this code from inside VSC it doesn't show pandas, but if I call it (python3 test.py) from the terminal, it does. So, clearly, I have to figure out why VSC isn't actually using the right environment.

```
import pip

pip.main(["freeze"])
```

- this is getting even stranger; at @jillcheng's suggestion, I looked in the actual env directory and it doesn't have the package installed. This jives with the problem and the above test (running pip freeze from inside py code):
  [image]
- it does NOT, however, match up with the fact that if I activate the environment from the terminal window, it shows the package, as shown in the earlier screenshot.

Thank you!
Dylan

Comment: Did you try to run the python script directly from this terminal instead of using the run-function of VSC?

Comment: Is your promlem that VSC displays it wrong, or that the code does not run?

Comment: @Dylan Kaufman You could try the following command to check it: 1. Please try to use 'pip --version' in the VSCode terminal to check whether the current used 'pip' is from the current environment; 2. You could use 'pip list' to view whether the module 'pandas' has been installed in the list.

Comment: @cagcoach, it runs fine in the terminal, and does not run in VSC. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @JillCheng, I ran pip --version and pip3 --version, and got the same 19.x both times, so I upgraded it to 20.2.2. pip3 list and pip3 freeze both display pandas 1.1.1, as I expect. Thank you for getting back to me. I don't know how to see what VSC is seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it is command that you could refer to the following steps:

1. Enter the current virtual environment in VSCode.
2. Enter '`pip --version` ' to check if the pip currently used is from the current environment: (This ensures that using pip to install pandas module will be put into the current virtual environment.)

[image]

3. List of pips before installing pandas module: (There is no module pandas in the list.)

[image]

After installation：(I use the command '`pip install pandas`'(windows10), mac: `pip3 install pandas`)

[image]

4. If it still has wavy lines, try reloading vscode.(`Ctrl+Shift+p`, `Developer: Reload windows` ). The module pandas can be used:

   [image]
5. Check the installation package:

   If the pip list shows the pands module, but we still can't use it, we can find the current virtual environment folder and check whether there is pandas installation package:

   [image]

Comment: That last one just turned up something interesting... When I run pip.main(["freeze"]) from inside the VSC window, I get a shorter list of installed packages that does not include pandas. When I start the environment in a terminal window (in VSC or just a plain terminal), pip freeze on the command line shows me the larger number of packages I expect, including pandas. And the actual directory has the shorter list.

Comment: @Dylan Kaufman Is the entire content of "site-packages" in the screenshot you updated? Except for the expected module 'pandas' in the folder, is there a 'pip' installation package? When you use "pip3 --version", does it appear to come from the current virtual environment? (Like step 2 of my answer).
If there is no pip module package: 1. You could try to install pip. Reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py  2. You could try to copy the 'pandas' module installation package from other projects in the same environment to this virtual environment.

Comment: OK, so that is curious. When I run pip3 --version in the environment that isn't working, it is showing the /usr/local/lib version under python 3.7, same as if I'm not in the environment. So clearly the environment isn't set up right. I will delete it and try again...

Comment: I just re-read your answer, @jillcheng, and it's exactly what you predicted. Sorry I was being dense! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Dylan Kaufman You're welcome! It is common that we all encounter various problems in the process of learning.

Comment: I think I have the exact same issue, but even after getting my pandas package (and other packages) installed in the same virtual environment selected in VS Code, I still get the same error: No module named pandas.